# When Using statement should be used?

Tags: c#, using-statement

A lot of people on SO pointed out that I should use `using` statement more often. So I am practicing.

The problem is that I can't decide when to use it and when not to use it. When I think I should use it, then I get errors such as in this example (PS. HashPhrase is a class created by me):

```
        using (HashPhrase hash = new HashPhrase())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString =
                "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                "Data Source=" + filePath + ";" +
                "Persist Security Info=False;" +
                "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + hash.ShortHash(pass) + ";";
        }
```

But it gives me an error: `'Password_Manager.HashPhrase': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'`

But in this example it works fine:

```
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString =
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + filePath + ";" +
            "Persist Security Info=False;" +
            "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + hash.ShortHash(pass) + ";";

        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Are there any quick guidelines how to determine when `using` statement should be used?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question already touches on the answer.

If the type implements the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface then you should aim to use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) whenever possible (that is, always, unless there's a compelling reason not to).

And if the type doesn't implement `IDisposable` then you can't use `using`, and the compiler will tell you so, as you've already discovered.

Comment: @downvoter: Would you care to explain your reasons for the downvote?

Answer (score 5):

You should use a `using` statement whenever the class implements the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface.

It's a shorthand for wrapping the object in a try-finally block to ensure the object's `Dispose` method is always called to release any resources, regardless of whether an exception is thrown.

To check, right-click the class name in Visual Studio and select *Go To Declaration* to open it in the Object Browser.  You can then check easily whether the class or its base types implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
using (var r = new R())
{
   // use r
}
```

the class `R` should implement the `IDisposing` interface.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to see if the object implements the IDisposable interface. So, right click the object/class in question, select Go to Definition from the dropdown (or press F12), and see if the class implements IDisposable. Note, in a class that implements many interfaces/other classes, you may need to actually check those classes to see if they implement IDisposable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I don't check first if a class implements `IDisposable` (since this might be buried in a base class), I just code a `Using` block if I think it makes sense, and if it fails to compile, I roll back to a standard construction. Lazy? Yeah, a bit. But it can be faster.

Eg, VB:

```
Using oSerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(MyType))
    ...
End Using
```

Eg, C#:

```
using (XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType)))
{
    ...
}
```

Though I think this *should* be possible, neither of the above fragments will actually compile because `XmlSerializer` doesn't implement `IDisposable` (which I find a bit strange to be honest considering that associated classes such as `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` *do* implement `IDisposable`).

So then you can just roll back to standard construction.

VB:

```
Dim oSerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(MyType))
...
```

C#:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));
...
```

I certainly agree with using `Using` where it's available; it's clean, concise and you get what's advertised in disposal and clean-up. Nice!

Comment: It drives me nuts when someone down-votes but doesn't have the, let's call it "nerve", to identify themselves by saying why. What's the problem??